# Sentry.io doesn't capture errors when Spring Boot running in production?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, sentry

There is Spring Boot application that runs on the server without exposing to external world. I connected Sentry to monitor it but never got any errors, even I have tons of them in the logs.

By ***without exposing to external world*** I mean that there is no open url that everyone can use for API connection.

How should I configure `Sentry` in order to get errors? Should I fall down to other scenarios, not [default Spring Boot app configuration](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/integrations/#spring)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fight with this problem for some time but it seems that either some of error messages were lost on the way or `Sentry.io` default configuration for `Spring Boot` sends messages with low threshold, so 1 error message for several actual errors.

In the end, it fixed itself.

Comment: is it possible to configure the threshold?

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles Threshold for sending logs to sentry.io? 

 Look at their docs for more details.  I think the most relevant will be: https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/manage-event-stream-guide/#6-rate-limiting

Comment: Yes, I meant if it's possible to configure Sentry so it sends one message per actual error

Answer (score 2):

Sentry doesn't need to connect to your application. When you add Sentry's SDK to your app and configure it with the correct `DSN`, your app will connect to Sentry to send errors as they occur.

For that you need to make sure the `DSN` you used goes to the project your expect to see the events in Sentry. That could be a reason why you don't see the events.

Perhaps your server has not access to the Internet? Or if it does, it requires use of an internal proxy server which was not configured in your server/application/sdk.

Comment: Do you know how to proxy app? I have `nginx` and Spring Boot but I found no information how to do proxy in `Sentry.io` docs. Is it `nginx` or Spring Boot related?

Comment: You can configure a proxy to your java process (https://memorynotfound.com/configure-http-proxy-settings-java/). But first make sure you do need a proxy. Can you access the Internet from your server without a proxy?

Comment: Yes, it exactly what break my head. I communicate with MWS but just don't allow direct call to API from outside.